# How do I make the onboard sound of the p8b75-m lx being sent via a dvi-hdmi cable?

Tags: audio, motherboard, hdmi, dvi, sound-card

My Motherboard is a p8b75-m lx and I connected a dvi-hdmi-cable to it. The dvi head is on the mobo's side, the hdmi head on a SAMSUNG flat TV.

I read on this Forum, that some graphic cards provide Sound being sent through the hdmi-dvi-cable and some don't. The onboard Sound capabilities of the mobo with respect to this Feature were not mentioned in the Manual. 
I do not know how to find out the Name of the onboard Sound chip of the mobo.

I would like to know whether my mobo's onboard Sound is capable of this Feature and if it is, how to make it happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously HDMI supports audio over the cable, but as far as I know DVI-I (you have dvi-i dual link on the motherboard) does not, by its standard.

Some ATI and Nvidia devices can send audio out of the the DVI-I using non-standard extensions. But your board has a VIA VT1708S audio chipset, and it is unclear to me if this will send audio over dvi-I, though I strongly doubt that it will. You should research this though.

If it does support this feature, you will need to go into the driver settings, or audio command applet, or any VIA driver configuration applet and find the setting and set it. Again, it may not be supported.

You can get a device that takes the dvi-i (ensure it is the dual link type for higher resolution support) and audio and muxes it together for HDMI, but this might introduce latency and looks like would be limited to stereo (because you do not have SPDIF?).

It might be better to get a current GPU with HDMI-out for the same price as an adapter. ATI and Nvidia GPUs usually have a driver for audio over HDMI and these will also support 5.1 pass-through (from movies).

Comment: Perfect,you re the best ....around